# upload featured image in custom post type from frontend

Tags: images, front-end

I am trying to upload featured image from frontend and my id is also inserted in post_meta but image is not uploaded in media library

https://www.screencast.com/t/Uakjtxi9ojv

**Here is my code.**

```
            $uploaddir = wp_upload_dir();
            $file = $_FILES['cptFeatured'];

            $uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename( $file['name'] );

            move_uploaded_file( $file["tmp_name"] , $uploadfile );
            $filename = basename( $uploadfile );

            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename['name']), null );

            $attachment = array(
                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'menu_order' => $_i + 1000
            );


            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile, $cpt_id );

            update_post_meta($cpt_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
            set_post_thumbnail( $cpt_id, $attach_id );
```

cptFeatured is name of input field. and cpt_id is post id.

Comment: What's your code?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I have updated my question.

Comment: Does the image show up inside your uploads folder?

Comment: @Swen yes it is in uploads/2018/04 folder but it is of only 1 size. and it is not generating more images of different size like wordpress do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the [wp_insert_attachment()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) function, which states the following in the Codex:

> This function is part of the low-level API used by WordPress for handling attachments. To perform the entire attachment upload and insertion process at once, you will want to use media_handle_upload() instead in most cases.

So to automatically generate the image resizes and an attachment entry in the database, use the [media_handle_upload()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) function instead.